# Python - добавление новых данных из функции

Tags: python, pandas

Столкнулся с проблемой, имеется dataset, вопрос крутится вокруг 3 столбцов:

1. time_spend_company - int64
2. promotion_last_5years - int64
3. salary - object

Планировал на основе данных с трех столбцов образовать новый, написал такую функцию:

```
    def payment(time,promotion,value):
    if time["time_spend_company"] >= 5 & promotion["promotion_last_5years"] < 1 & value["salary"] == "low":
        return "non-fair"
    else:
        return "fair"
```

Думал как добавить в новый столбец, у меня получилось так:

```
    hr['fair remuneration'] = list(map(payment, hr["time_spend_company"], 
                                   hr["promotion_last_5years"], hr["salary"]))
```

Выдает такую ошибку: 'int' object is not subscriptable
И указывает на time_spend_company.
Прошу помочь с данным вопросом, возможно я вообще не туда иду.

Comment: для начала, вы и так передаете серии (столбцы) в свою функцию.  откуда у вас появилась такая ерунда как `time["time_spend_company"]` вместо просто `time`?

Comment: далее, зачем писать непонятную функцию, мапить ее, если можно все сделать векторно, например через np.where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще, да и быстрее сделать так:

```py
mask = (hr["time_spend_company"] >= 5) & \
       (hr["promotion_last_5years"] < 1) & \
       (hr["salary"] == "low")
hr.loc[ mask, 'fair remuneration'] = 'non-fair'
hr.loc[~mask, 'fair remuneration'] = 'fair'
```

Но можно и через функцию, тогда как-то так:

```py
def payment(row):
    if row["time_spend_company"] >= 5 & \
       row["promotion_last_5years"] < 1 & \
       row["salary"] == "low":
        return "non-fair"
    else:
        return "fair"

hr['fair remuneration'] = hr.apply(payment, axis=1) # тут насчёт axis не уверен
```

Comment: Благодарю! Даже не догадывался, что так можно сделать

Comment: С `Pandas` нужно приучаться мыслить "векторно", то есть оперировать сразу всеми значениями столбцов. Но можно и через функцию как у вас и `apply`, я добавил вариант, но не помню там `axis=1`, `axis=0` или вообще не нужно `axis`.

Comment: `hr['fair remuneration'] =  'fair' `   `hr['fair remuneration'][mask] =  'non-fair'` .

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Можно и таким образом, одно из присваиваний без маски. Но вторая строка плохая, из-за повторной индексации `Pandas` ругаться будет, что вы оперируете срезом датасета, а не самим датасетом. `.loc` - рекомендуемый способ присвоения данных в датасет.

Comment: @CrazyElf Вынужден возразить. Я так понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду **SettingWithCopyWarning**. Если я ошибаюсь - прошу прощения, тогда попрошу пояснить, какое именно предупреждение или исключение Вы имеете ввиду. Но, если все же речь идет о нем, то это исключение возникает вне зависимости от того используем мы `.loc` или используем непосредственную индексацию, вопрос в изменении оригинальной таблицы. Что касается моего кода, то как я его привел будет работать. А вот такая форма: `hr[mask]['fair remuneration']` - как раз выбросит то самое исключение.

Comment: @CrazyElf Вот видос от разработчиков (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIbYomIcl34&list=PLGVZCDnMOq0qgYUt0yn7F80wmzCnj2dEq&index=13&t=100s ) где разбираются все примеры, в которых будет предупреждение, а в каких - нет. Наш случай там тоже есть.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov Да, я имел в виду `SettingWithCopyWarning`, наверное да, я не прав, по маске может и не будет. Привык просто, что двойная индексация это плохо.